# iOS local notification: I would like to execute a function upon reentering the app via local notification

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm working with XCode 4.6, and am trying to build a local notification feature on iOS that will execute a function upon reentering the app.Basically I would like to change the text in some of the labels and add some sound upon reentering the app. I thought I was on the right track, but only some parts of my code work when reentering the app via local notification.

First I added this function to my AppDelegate:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"test1");   //this traces successfully 
    myAppViewController * controller = [myAppViewController alloc];
    [controller doSomething];  //calling a function in my myAppViewController.m
}
```

I thought I had figured it out, but now only the NSLog works in my function in myAppViewController.m:

```
-(void)doSomething{
    NSLog(@"do something"); //traces successfully 
    self.notificationTime.text=@"something else"; //nothing happens here, it works in other functions but not here
    [self doSomethingElse]; //calling another function from this function for further testing 
}
```

The next function is called....

```
-(void)doSomethingElse{
    NSLog(@"do something else"); //this works
    //this whole thing doesn't work -- no sound -- 
    NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"cash" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    NSAssert(url, @"URL is valid.");
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [self.player prepareToPlay];
    [self.player play];
    //this doesn't work again
    self.notificationTime.text=@"something else";
}
```

I was hoping to get some general advice here and it would be much appreciated. If anyone knows a complete different way of solving the problem, that would be great as well!

Comment: Are you updating an existing view controller?? Does the view is visible before getting notification??

Answer (score 1):

The `didReceiveLocalNotification` method is only called when you application is running in the foreground. If you see a badge and click on the App to start it, then you need to process the local notification using `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`) To get at your local notification in either of these two methods, use `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` as a key to the options dictionary.

Note, once you extract the local notification from the launch options, it is a viable approach to call your `didReceiveLocalNotification` method.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to allocate a second instance of the app controller. You can just use `self`. If you do that, does the code work as expected?